# Using Http/2 with ASP.NET self hosted webapi

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, owin, http2

Is it possible to handle `HTTP/2` requests using `OWIN Self-Host ASP.NET Web API 2`? I want to allow both, `HTTP 1.1` and `HTTP/2` but could not found a lot about this.

Does any one use this already and know how to use it?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP/2 support comes in .NET Framework 4.6 (and 4.6.1) on Windows 10 only,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6/

Comment: The version of .NET does not matter for self-host, but you do need Win10.

Comment: @Tratcher do you now the reason for that?

Comment: The implementation of HTTP/2 is down in a native windows library named Http.Sys that IIS and HttpListener depend on. The feature was added in Win10, it is not a .NET feature. The server does not need to opt into the feature, it should just work.  There is one new optional public API in System.Web (push promise), but there were no API additions for HttpListener.

Comment: @Tratcher you should also state that HTTP/2 standard was only approved in 2015, and Microsoft can only add the support to its latest Windows release reliably.

Comment: And do you know in Server editions what is the minimum version?

Comment: @JairoAndresVelascoRomero no server edition released from Microsoft right now supports HTTP/2. The upcoming Server 2016 will be the first to support it.